# Run external Sqoop command from python

Tags: python, subprocess, sqoop, os.system

I can run this command from terminal:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/eco --table sso_user --username user --password pwd --target-dir /hoy/ecoid --direct --m 5 --map-column-java newsdata=String --map-column-hive newsdata=STRING
```

and works fine. But when I try:

```
cmd = 'sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/eco --table sso_user --username user --password pwd --target-dir /hoy/ecoid --direct --m 5 --map-column-java newsdata=String --map-column-hive newsdata=STRING'
exec cmd
```

I get: `Syntax error`

```
os.system(cmd)
```

I get: `sh: 1: sqoop: not found`

Finally, if I try:

```
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

I get: `/bin/sh: 1: sqoop: not found`

BUT! when I try in python shell:

```
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.system('sqoop import --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/eco --table sso_user --username user --password pwd --target-dir /hoy/ecoid --direct --m 5 --map-column-java newsdata=String --map-column-hive newsdata=STRING')
```

It works!

I think the problem is related to the output, but I am not sure.

Thanks for reading and helping me!

Comment: Find where your `sqoop` executable is and use the full path in your command. Also, use `subprocess` methods for calling your external executables.

Comment: @zwer `subprocess.call(cmd)` is the right way to use it in this case?

Comment: If you only need the return code, yes. If you need to capture more of the output use `subprocess.check_output()` and if you need full control over the execution process you can create your own `subprocess.Popen()` instance.

Comment: @zwer now when `subprocess.call(cmd)` I get: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: try building your command as a list so you don't have to deal with proper escaping:  `cmd = ["path/to/sqoop", "import", "--connect", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/eco", "--table", "sso_user", "--username", "user", "--password", "pwd", "--target-dir", "/hoy/ecoid",  "--direct", "--m", "5", "--map-column-java", "newsdata=String", "--map-column-hive newsdata=STRING"]`

Comment: @zwer I used `command.split()`, now I get an error related to `$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME` I set it in bashrc but not working, well, it is something new. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you have an issue with your environment variables - namely, the shell you're running your python script from doesn't have that specific environment variable defined (and its `$PATH` is different, too, that's why it couldn't find `sqoop`). You can pass custom environment variables to your `subprocess.call()` via the `env` argument if you want to fix all from within Python.